# Using Context in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-context

I couldn't use context in `FragmentPagerAdapter`. `RadioGroup(this)` gives me undefined error. I used `getContext()` instead of this but couldn't achieve it

```
private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);  // what can I use instead of "this" ?

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am not sure why you are instantiating a RadioGroup in a FragmentPagerAdapter, but anyway you can get the context by modifying the constructor of the class:

```
private Context context; 

/** Constructor of the class */
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
    super(fm);
    context = c;
}
```

Then you can add the context when you create your FragmentPagerAdapter.